# How do you reference the git repository root directory in Xcode build settings?

Tags: xcode, git, build-settings

How do you reference the git repository root directory in Xcode build settings?

We have a project where our original source code comprises 39 modules (framework targets) spread around in various levels of subdirectories.

In addition we keep certain modules like Crashlytics in the repository root in a folder called "ThirdPartyFrameworks" and then we have "Carthage" also at the repository root.

Currently each framework references all third party dependencies through paths relative to each framework's project directory, e.g. `$(PROJECT_DIR)/../../../Carthage/Build/iOS` etc. However, if you want to reorganize the project, and move a project to a new spot, then all these kinds of links will break, since they're relative.

What I would greatly prefer to do is just have one shared config file that references these framework search paths like: `$(GIT_ROOT)/Carthage` and be done with it. However I don't see any way to reference the repo root or workspace root that way.

Does anyone know a way to do this...? Thanks.

Comment: The quoted paths, are they coming from the `project.pbxproj` file? There is a format, you can look for the: `isa = XCBuildConfiguration; buildSettings = {`, and the values are pseudo-variables. (See how `PRODUCT_NAME = "$(TARGET_NAME)";` is used. The only limit: I don't know how the IDE reacts to hand-crafted values.
`